# echo pages with any kind of extensions - file_get_contents(

Tags: php

Using AJAX im loading content from pages with extension .html:

```
$folders = array('folder_1/', 'folder_2/');
foreach ($folders as $folder) {

    $url = ($folder . $_REQUEST['datastring']); /* 'datastring' = loading with AJAX */
        if (file_exists($url.'.html')) {
            echo file_get_contents($url.'.html');
        }
}
```

However i would like to be able to load content from pages with any type of extension - fx .html, .php, .text etc. How can this be done? Ive tried this and other solutions, but with no luck:

```
        if (file_exists($url.'.*')) {
                echo file_get_contents($url.'.*');
        }
```

Comment: Do you actually have the file name?  `somefilename.*` isn't a file, so it's not going to get any contents.

Comment: So, you want *every file* with the name of `$url` with any extension?  Maybe [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) can help?

Comment: Be careful with loading content from _any_ extension. Configuration files and PHP files could be read (like database passwords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your existing code here is one way:

```
$folders = array('folder_1/', 'folder_2/');

foreach($folders as $folder) {
    $url = ($folder . $_REQUEST['datastring']);
    foreach(glob($url . '.*') as $file) {
        echo file_get_contents($file);
    }
}
```